# Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 Pro (YT3-X90L) factory image, OTA update or backup needed

Tags: locked-out, frp, lenovo-yoga

I was playing around trying out some new stuff with my Lenovo Yoga tab and locked it. There is an old Google account on it, but I can't remember it.

I've tried so many things:

1. I've tried to factory reset it, but it's still locked.
2. I've tried to flash TWRP in the hope to do something more, but unlocking my tab in a locked state isn't allowed.
3. I was able to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCzrnnh2K1w) to minute 9:08. But the option "Email and password" is not there anymore. I guess they patched it with 6.0.1.
4. I tried to flash a stock ROM or TWRP with LenovoDownloader(QcomDLoader). The stock ROM file is: `Lenovo_Yoga_Tablet_3_YT3-X90L_ENG_S200028_1609230146`. Even it's a German device, this file was the only one I could find. But the LenovoDownloader won't recognize my device. The windows stay white with no entries. I guess I installed the correct driver for this device and Windows recognizes them as a removable device if I plug it in via USB.
5. I've tried to use `adb` and `fastboot boot oem unlock`. But these commands aren't working in a locked state.
6. With a trick, I could open the Settings and be full of hope to activate the developer options to set USB debugging to active. But these developer options aren't available either with this "user".
7. There is an APK for showing the "Email and password" interface. I could install it, but it force closes right after starting it.
8. I've tried several tools to bypass this FRP: WinDroid Toolkit, D-G Unlocker, Realterm, but NOTHING.

What could I do further?

Specs for the device:

- Lenovo Yoga Tab 3 Pro (YT3-X90L)
- Lenovo/YT3_l0_row_lte
- 6.0.1/MMB29M/LenovoYT3-X90L_S200307_170614

Comment: What do you mean by you locked it?  After resetting, doss the tab still request an unlock code/pattern/password?

Comment: no that's not. It just requests an old google account. It says "Welcome" and then it requires an internet connection to verify the google account linked to my device. But i can't get the google account again.

Comment: Ah okay, that's an FRP lock even flashing ROM won't bypass that. There are dozens of tutorials on how to bypass the Factory Reset Protection.

Comment: Hey, first thank you for your help. But, i've tried to factory reset. It worked, but the device is still locked. Or do you mean another kind of resett?

Comment: The factory reset only reset user data. The FRP partition can't be wiped by a factory reset. But I think downgrading your device build could help bypass the FRP.

Comment: and how to downgrade my device? Sorry, but you might have a clue on how to do it.

Comment: Also posted on XDA: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/yt3-x90l-lock-state-locked-recovery-image-needed.3745106/

Answer (score 1):

I've written it down. Translation by Google, but I think it's all good.

Situation:
"Confirm account: The device has been reset. To continue, sign in with a Google Account that was previously synced on this device."

Explanation:
The device has been blocked by repeated input of the wrong password, pattern, etc., and can only be unlocked with the Google account of the owner.
A factory reset or hard reset does not help here, as the account information is saved in its own FRP partition and will not be deleted when the factory state is restored.

Solution:

1. Connect the device to Wi-Fi and Internet access.
2. Before confirming "Next", select another hotspot here
3. Go to "Advanced Settings" and change the proxy settings of any hotspot to Manual.
4. In the text input field of the proxy settings, enter any word: e.g. Test
5. Now, mark this word and select "Assist" in the context menu.
6. Selecting this "Assist" option opens the Google search application.
7. You can now not only browse the Internet through this search but also search for and open installed programs.
8. We are looking for Chrome, open the internet browser, go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), and search for DPC test ([APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/sample-developer/test-dpc/test-dpc-4-0-6-release/test-dpc-4-0-6-android-apk-download/))
9. After downloading this application, go back to the Google search application.
10. Here we enter "Download" to search for the download application.
11. In Downloads, we can now find and install the downloaded app.
12. To allow the installation of this .apk, you must allow the installation of "unknown sources" in the settings.
13. Either you go here on the installation itself on "Settings", or you search for "Settings" on the Google search app.
14. After completing the installation of the DPC-Test program, start it with "Open".
15. The app itself will register as a device owner and now allows us to set up a new Google Account as an owner.
16. If this is set up, it will also be included in the FRP partition.
17. In the event of a new factory reset, the device is reset, the DPC-Test program is removed and the device can be freshly set up in the factory settings.

After the takeover of the owner, the reason for blocking the device was not present anymore and the old owner was overwritten. This will be overwritten in the FRP partition as well with the new account and the old one no longer be queried.